# What is the definition of $\sum_{n = - \infty}^{\infty} a_n$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, laurent-series

I know that in Complex Analysis we use sums of the form $\displaystyle\sum_{n = - \infty}^{\infty} a_n$

What is the actual meaning of this symbol? I expect that under some nice enough conditions, it would be equal to something like $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$, where $b_{2k} = a_k$ and $b_{2k+1} = a_{-k}$. But what is the actual definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum is defined as $$\displaystyle\sum_{n = - \infty}^{\infty} a_n:= \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{N} a_n+\lim_{M\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{M} a_{-n}$$

Comment: In particular, we need both the positive subsequence and the negative subsequence to exist, instead of picking some Cauchy principal value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are there any theorems which allow you to play around with the sums, such as I did in my post?

Comment: The usual stuff with rearranging two infinite sums - absolute convergence allows you to reorder terms.

Comment: If you know that the sums are absolutely convergent (i.e. $\sum|a_n|$ converges), then you may rearrange terms and sum in whatever manner you like, including defining the sequence $b_n$ as you did.  However, if the sum is conditionally convergent (i.e. convergent but not absolutely convergent), then the Riemann series theorem states that you can rearrange the terms of the series so that the sum converges to any number you like, or diverges.